# Would a semiconductor in an optical fiber work as an optical transistor?

Tags: optics, electrons, semiconductor-physics, refraction, electronics

According to [this website](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=3064), the electron density affects the refractive index.

I planned on creating a doped semiconductor in an optical fiber. This meaning that I would dope the glass it reflects inside to have extra holes. This way, when a voltage is applied, the electrons would flow, increasing or decreasing the electron density.

In theory, would this work as an optical transistor (no matter efficiency)?

Or (bonus question) If I had multiple pieces of glass touching, each doped to a different amount (increasing as going right), could this work as a way to switch which glass path photons flowed through with voltage? (Because the refractive index is being changed)

Each column of lines represents a strip of glass (more doped as it goes right). The arrow is where the photons go in and the +/- is the voltage

```
  |||||
  |||||
+ ||||| -
  |||||
  |||||
  ^
```

Comment: Silica (what optical fibers are made out of) is not typically considered a semiconductor. You'll have a hard time getting any appreciable (even picoamps) current flowing through it. You might want to study [semiconductor optical amplifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_amplifier#Semiconductor_optical_amplifier) for a semiconductor structure that varies its optical transmissivity depending on an electrical current.

Comment: @ThePhoton oh, thank you. Would it be possible to use silicon as the refractive material? This way I could pass current  through it, and light. I just don’t know if light can flow through it.

Comment: Silicon will absorb light with wavelengths below about 1100 nm. If you are using a longer wavelength, then yes.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you so much for this. It helps